# mysql fetch object from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

help me with this little issues, i have two tables, taxi and hotel
which have same column name "pangkalan1", and i wanna create some filter that , when i ran this query "SELECT * 
FROM taxi,hotel 
WHERE taxi.pangkalan1 = hotel.pangkalan1
AND taxi.pangkalan1 IN ('A','A');" and the results is list of taxi or hotel that have pangkalan1=A,and works , until i confuse with the fetch object in my sql

can anybody help me?

this my code

```
    <?php
function datarelasi(){
$ambil = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM taxi,hotel 
WHERE taxi.pangkalan1 = hotel.pangkalan1
AND taxi.pangkalan1 IN ('A','A');");
While ($row=mysql_fetch_object($ambil)) {
$nama    = stripslashes($row->taxi->nama);
Echo $nama;
}
}
echo datarelasi();
?>
```

the results is

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$taxi in C:\xampp\htdocs\dss\inc\relasi.php on line 21

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\dss\inc\relasi.php on line 21
```

, i just want to fetch individual object from table, taxi->name, or hotel->name,

thanks

Comment: When sending a request you get a stream. This stream is built with rows that all have the same structure. $row->taxi doesn't mean anything (unless you have a column named 'taxi'). You should be able to fetch the info you want with $row->nama.
You could also print your row to see what you have in it before doing blind operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should not be using the **mysql_** extension. Please look at MYSQLI_ or PDO as the modern alternative. If you continue to use the MYSQL_* extension sometime soon when you want to upgrade your version of PHP, that extension will no longer work

If you are not sure what is being returned from a `mysql_fetch_object()` call then just dump it using `print_r()` But normally you shoudl get a class property for each column you select in the query.

You also dont need the `IN('A','A')` as what you actually need to code is `taxi.pangkalan1 ='A'`

```
<?php
   function datarelasi() {
      $ambil = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM taxi,hotel 
                            WHERE taxi.pangkalan1 = hotel.pangkalan1
                              AND taxi.pangkalan1 ='A'");

      While ($row=mysql_fetch_object($ambil)) {
         // dump whats returned when you are not sure
         // print_r($row);

          $nama    = stripslashes($row->nama);
          Echo $nama;
      }

   }
   // call the function
   datarelasi();
?>
```

Comment: i try print_r($row); it just only show table from hotel, but i try query "SELECT * FROM taxi,hotel WHERE taxi.pangkalan1 = hotel.pangkalan1 AND taxi.pangkalan1 IN ('A','A')" phpmyadmin and the results is both table, (taxi and hotel), any ideas?

Comment: Do you have more than one column with the same name in these 2 tables